# Accessing data in different parts of server() in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am having a problem with accessing data in different parts of my server() function. The basic structure is something like this:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # get the data from a file obtained from a textInput in the ui
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    file <- input$file$datapath
    # process the file and return a new dataframe

  })

  output$head <- renderTable({
    mydf <- data()
    head(mydf)
  })

  output$tail <- renderTable({
    mydf <- data()
    tail(mydf)
  })

})
```

I would like to avoid having to call data() twice but I haven't found a way to do that.

---

Edit following the comment by @KentJohnson

What I am trying to achieve is for the user to select a file to open, using `textInput`, and after the file is opened, the app should do some processing and populate the two tables in the ui. After this, the user then chooses some other actions which also require the same data.

I wanted to avoid having to call `data()` twice but I haven't found a way to do that. I was assuming that each call would mean reading from the file each time. The file is very large so that is my motivation.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid calling `data()` twice? You are using `reactive` exactly as intended. `data()` will only be evaluated once for any value of `input$file`.

Comment: @KentJohnson Thank you.  I thought that by calling `data()` twice it would read the file twice, am I wrong ? I have updated the question with some more info.

Comment: Kent's correct. This is the value of `reactive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KentJohnson points out, `reactive` already achieves your goal. The expression that makes up data...

```
req(input$file)
file <- input$file$datapath
# process the file and return a new dataframe
```

...only runs when `input$file$datapath` changes. It does not rerun each time `data()` is called.

Comment: Thank you, so if `input$file$datapath` has not changed, then I assume the result of `data()` is cached ?

Comment: @JoeKing Yes, exactly. Good example [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/)

Answer (score 1):

Putting your two tables into an `observe` environment makes it possible to call `data()` only twice, but I don't know if it will fit with what you want to do. Notice that here, I didn't put a `textInput` or things like that because my point was to show the `observe` environment. I'll let you adapt it to your situation (since you didn't put the `ui` part in your post):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  fileInput("file", 
            "Import a CSV file", 
            accept = ".csv"),
  tableOutput("head"),
  tableOutput("tail")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # get the data from a file obtained from a textInput in the ui
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    inFile <- input$file
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = F, sep = ";")
    # process the file and return a new dataframe

  })

  observe({
    mydf <- data()
    if (is.null(mydf)){
      output$head <- renderTable({})
      output$tail <- renderTable({})
    }
    else {
      output$head <- renderTable({
        head(mydf)
      })
      output$tail <- renderTable({
        tail(mydf)
      })
    }
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:** I misunderstood the OP's question, see @SmokeyShakers' answer for a more appropriate answer.

Comment: This isn't correct, the expression within `data` is only called once by virtue of it being a `reactive`.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers I don't understand why this isn't correct because ```data()``` is called only once (in the ```observe``` environment) instead of twice as in the OP's post. Of course ```data()``` needs to be defined as a reactive expression before

Comment: The concern in the question is the rerunning of the expression within `data`. OP isn't trying to avoid writing `data()`, rather avoid reloading and reprocessing a dataset.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Okay I get it now, in fact there's nothing to change in the OP's code to adress his/her concern (as you explained in your answer), right?

Comment: Yes,exactly, just a misunderstanding of `reactive` by the OP

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Okay, I'll let my example (it might be useful to someone) but redirect on your answer